# how do I handle '&' in perl cgi url parameter where the parameter value contains an '&' sign

Tags: perl, cgi

I am trying to pass parameters in URL and reading the parameters with param().
one of my parameter values contain an '&' sign, hence while reading the value through param() it skips the part after '&'.
Is there any way I can use this method without compromising the value that contain '&'?

Example:

http://someurl/?brand=Bell%20&%20Ross&category=Wrist%20Watch%20Dealers&qq_cat_id=8798798

The value for the parameter brand is coming "Bell" rather than "Bell & Ross".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special to handle param values that contain `&`.  For example, `$cgi->param('brand')` would return `Bell & Ross` for

```
http://someurl/?brand=Bell%20%26%20Ross&category=Wrist%20Watch%20Dealers&qq_cat_id=8798798
                             ^^^
```

The problem is that the url in the OP wasn't properly constructed; the `brand` parameter wasn't set to `Bell & Ross`. All of the following will correctly construct the url:

```
use URI::Escape qw( uri_escape );

my $url = 'http://someurl/';
$url .= "?" . join('&', 
   join('=', map { uri_escape($_) } brand     => $brand),
   join('=', map { uri_escape($_) } category  => $category),
   join('=', map { uri_escape($_) } qq_cat_id => $qq_cat_id),
);
```

or

```
use URI qw( );

my $url = URI->new('http://someurl/');
$url->query_form(
   brand     => $brand,
   category  => $category,
   qq_cat_id => $qq_cat_id,
);
```

or

```
use URI             qw( );
use URI::QueryParam qw( );

my $url = URI->new('http://someurl/');
$url->query_param_append( brand     => $brand );
$url->query_param_append( category  => $category );
$url->query_param_append( qq_cat_id => $qq_cat_id );
```

Comment: The second method worked perfectly fine. Thanks a lot @ikegami for helping with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your URL doesn't mean what you think it means. And it doesn't mean what the person who created it thought it meant. The `&` character has a special meaning in URLs - it separates different parameters. Any URL parser that encounters your URL would split the parameters at that point (which is why you're getting "Bell " rather than "Bell & Ross").

If you want a `&` in a URL that isn't treated as a separator, then you need to URL-encode the `&` (which will turn it into `%26`).

The problem is not with the code that is processing the URL. The problem is with the code that is generating the URL. That's what needs to be fixed.

(**Updated:** I originally claimed that the URL was invalid. That's not true.)

Comment: No, the OP's url is perfectly valid.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose you're right. It's valid; it just doesn't mean what they think it means.